# How you answer for such question on job interview: Why would you like to be a Project Manager?

Tags: interview

I would like to ask you Directors, PMs, and HRs for something. Lately I have been on several job interviews. The question what very often I have heard was: "Why would you like to be a Project Manager?". What would be your answer? Why you are a Project Manager? What answer you give? What answer would you like to hear?

Comment: I would want to hear your honest answer, not what you think I would want to hear.

Comment: As written, this is a discussion question that is off-topic everywhere on Stack Exchange. Your reasons are your own; you should probably give those reasons some thought.

Comment: I just want to share the views and opinions about this topic. I do not expect to get solution here. Just want to compere what leads me with others and make a discussion. So for what is Stack Exchange if not for such purposes? It should be open for various discussions.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a discussion site, nor is it the place to solicit opinions or ask "questions" that don't have even the expectation of a solution. See http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for details, or bring your concerns up on meta.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't the kind of question that fits our Q&A model. Discussion and polling really isn't what Stack Exchange is about. With these "getting to know you" type questions, literally every single possible answer is a correct answer, and this makes it hard to vote them to the top and also discourages answers with facts, references, or specific expertise. Instead, [edit] your post to focus on the actual problem you're trying to solve. What is it that you're hoping to learn. Good luck! :)

Comment: Check out [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more guidance.

Comment: If every answer is good you can always choose the best one. And if you look for other question answers you can see that very often there is more than one right answer.But always is chosen the best one. The only solution is to create new site like stack exchange but with open mind and no strange and too strict rules as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been asked this, you should think about your reasons before you go for another interview. If you want to be a PM, you must know why. I can't provide you with an answer that would be honest for you, but I can tell you that I am a PM because I like to make change happen, I believe that I am good at working with and directing people to achieve this, and I enjoy the challenges that the work brings me. Your answers may be very different, so you need to work this out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is simple, I like to work people, look how they grow with the appropriate suggestions and by showing them possibilities they can choose from. I like the meetings, being in the heart of hurricane where you have to save the situation. I do not expect that you tell me what I have to answer. I just want to know what drives your decisions about being PM.